# Prevent NodeJs express server from loading index in place of another resource

Tags: node.js, express, httpserver

How do I prevent node express server from reloading the index.html in place of other files it did not find?

I am  new to node, this is how the server is started:

```
// Starting express server
http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function () {
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

For example: if I include a script tag referring to "/bower/angular.js" which does not exist, I get the "Error parsing <" message because it tried to load index again.

This is extremely annoying, not to mention the disastrous effect when I try to load an angular template with an incorrect URL.

(Coming form Apache, I am trying hard not to call this default behavior "retarded". Can anyone please explain why I am not getting the old beautiful 404?)

Comment: Can you show the rest of the code where you serve index.html?

Answer (score 0):

I guess your looking for something like that?

```
app.get('/', express.static(index));
app.use(express.static(...resources path));
```